# Get the best 8 results of a sql query of 20?

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I need to get the 8 best results of the last 20 entry's.
To get the last 20 entry's i use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM uitslagen
WHERE lid_id = '12' AND type = 'comp' AND invoer = 'ja'
ORDER BY seizoen DESC, wedstrijd_nr DESC, lid_strokeplay_score ASC
LIMIT 20
```

But now there should be a sub-select that gets the 8 best/lowest lid_strokeplay_score results.

Comment: Wrap it in another select then. What's the problem?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? One with `OFFSET`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do mean saying "best results".

If you just need to take first 8 records from that dataset, all you need to do is to chenge LIMIT 20 to LIMIT 8:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM uitslagen 
 WHERE lid_id = '12' 
   AND type = 'comp' 
   AND invoer = 'ja' 
 ORDER BY seizoen DESC, wedstrijd_nr DESC, lid_strokeplay_score ASC 
 LIMIT 8
```

If you need to re-sort these 20 lines, the easiest and the most universal way would be to use another select statement over this one:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM uitslagen 
         WHERE lid_id = '12' 
           AND type = 'comp' 
           AND invoer = 'ja' 
         ORDER BY seizoen DESC, wedstrijd_nr DESC, lid_strokeplay_score ASC
        LIMIT 20)
ORDER BY /* here go all re-ordering criterias */
LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select becomes what's known as a `derived table` and you use it as input to a parent `select`

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT * FROM uitslagen WHERE lid_id = '12' AND type = 'comp' AND invoer = 'ja' ORDER BY seizoen DESC, wedstrijd_nr DESC, lid_strokeplay_score ASC LIMIT 20
)
ORDER BY lid_strokeplay_score ASC
LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers of ekochergin and Stu seem to be the same. But when I use the answer there are some error's.
This is the code I use now:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM(
      SELECT * FROM uitslagen WHERE lid_id = '12' AND type = 'comp' AND invoer = 'ja' ORDER BY seizoen DESC, wedstrijd_nr DESC, lid_strokeplay_score ASC LIMIT 20
    )
    ORDER BY lid_strokeplay_score ASC
    LIMIT 8");
    $result = mysql_num_rows($query);
    while($object = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
        $par_score = ($object->lid_strokeplay_score - '54');
    echo "$object->seizoen - $object->wedstrijd_nr - $object->lid_naam - $object->lid_stableford_score - $object->lid_strokeplay_score - $par_score<br>";
    }
```

And the error's I get:
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in whs.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in whs.php on line 7